# Why didn't Deanna Troi wear a uniform at the start?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I have looked over [the question about Deanna's change of uniform](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1839/why-did-deanna-troi-keep-wearing-a-starfleet-uniform-after-chain-of-command), but that does not explain why Deanna did not wear a uniform for the first few seasons of TNG.

What was the reason for such a high ranking officer such as herself to wear clothing that was much more revealing than any other officer or crewman on board?

Comment: I believe this *was* answered in the linked question. Out of universe, this was probably done for the same reason women in Starfleet wore miniskirts in the Kirk era: Ratings! Also, in the 60's, such clothing was [seen as "sticking it to the man"](http://www.buzzsawmag.org/2009/09/11/the-rise-and-fall-of-the-miniskirt-2/), much like long hair for men. I suspect the irony of institutionalizing the miniskirt did not escape the show's producers.

Comment: Jeff's answer in the linked question seems to answer it, at least as a theoretical.

Comment: This is answered fully in the second and third paragraphs of Jeff's answer to the first of the linked duplicates.