# Why doesn't Seven of Nine wear a Starfleet uniform?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, seven-of-nine

After Seven of Nine is de-borg-ified and joins the Voyager crew she wears a skin-tight catsuit, seemingly 24 hours a day. I have always just assumed the reason she didn't get a Starfleet uniform was simply because she wasn't officially a member of Starfleet. But, since a significant number of the Voyager crew was made up of Maquis members who all got Starfleet ranks and uniforms I'm not sure why this wasn't possible for Seven.

I assume the out-of-universe reason is, well... ratings! But has there been any in-universe explanation for Seven not getting a Starfleet uniform or rank?

Comment: I was actually wondering why Deanna Troi rarely wears her uniform in TNG. I suspect the in- and out-of-universe answers to that question are much the same as this one.

Comment: [Why didn't Deanna Troi wear a uniform at the start?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34308/68153). Seems being a councillor had a lot to do with it in-universe... out-of-universe was probably the same as Seven though :-)

Comment: Ratings were indeed a key concern when casting (and costuming) Jeri Ryan; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Seven_of_Nine#Background_information

Comment: T'pol also wears non-starfleet uniform much of the time. Crusher and Belana also wear slightly altered Starfleet uniforms.

Comment: @Durakken - There seems to be some latitude among the various crews over what they're wearing. The goal seems to be "clearly Starfleet" + "clean and tidy". Beyond that, I guess you get to pick and choose.

Comment: For Troi, maybe as the ship's counsellor she decided not to wear the uniform in order to seem more approachable, so that as a patient you would see her in a more casual, friendly light than as (in most crewmembers' cases) a _superior officer_ to whom they'd be addressing.

Comment: If she is only seven of nine, I would love to see nine of nine!!

Comment: @iMerchant - Nine of Nine could could easily be a burly male Hirogen :-) http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/P'Chan

Comment: @Ixrec  In the documentary "Chaos on the Bridge", Troy's outfit is discussed.  The writers wanted to play off her sex appeal with a non-uniform.   In one of the later shows, not Picard but a guest captain when Picard was on a mission, told her to get in "Proper attire" and she war a uniform from that point on.  The only explanation is that she was casual by choice, being counselor, people might feel less comfortable confiding to someone in uniform.  That's mt take on Troi, but the real reason was the writers and sex-appeal.    Then they discovered she looked good in a uniform and kept it.

Comment: ...Because they didn't have one handy that would fit Two Of Thirty-Eight?

Comment: @keshlam:  I prefer the Sev Trek name Ten of Ten.

Comment: ISTR the Doctor prescribing the catsuit to Seven for some doubletalk reason after he had removed most of her implants.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Seven is not given a Starfleet uniform because she is not Starfleet. She's not given a Starfleet rank because she had no Starfleet training. This is normal.

*With the exception of the Maquis* this is how Voyager handles all other non-Starfleet crew members such as Neelix and Kes. It's also consistent with how other non-Starfleet crew are handled in other series. The [Maquis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maquis) were a special case. Asking why the Maquis, and others, were given uniforms and ranks sheds light on why Seven, and others, were not.

On the Enterprise D [Acting Ensign](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Acting_ensign) Wesley Crusher didn't get to wear a uniform. He was only granted this privilege after receiving a field promotion to Ensign. In [Ménage à Troi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_Troi_(episode)) he missed his transport to the Academy and Picard felt he should not wait any longer. (Thanks @Ghanima)

[image: Wesley Crusher]

[Janeway decided it was paramount that the two crews integrate](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallax_(episode)) to better live together on Voyager in the coming years. This was made easier because many were ex-Starfleet ([Chakotay](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chakotay#Starfleet_Academy)) or had some Starfleet training ([B'Elanna](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B'Elanna_Torres#Starfleet_Academy)). Janeway granted them [provisional ranks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Provisional_officer) which is why they have different insignia from regular Starfleet. They were given Starfleet uniforms, [underwent Starfleet training](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Learning_Curve_(episode)), and were expected to act as Starfleet crew.

[image: Chakotay]

Tom Paris was pointed out by @Durakken in the comments. He's an ex-Starfleet, ex-Maquis criminal invited to Voyager by Janeway as a ["Starfleet observer"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Observer). Which appears to grant him the right to wear a uniform as he's wearing it before they head to the Delta Quadrant, but with no rank insignia. From the start Janeway is trying to bring Tom back into the fold. Upon losing their pilot, she reinstates Tom's former Starfleet rank of Lieutenant Junior Grade. Since he wasn't part of Chakotay's crew, and shows no attachment to the Maquis, he's treated as Starfleet to better integrate him into the crew.

What if Seven had rank? Now she's subordinate to people, people she might feel are inferior, something she does not deal well with. Worse, others would be subordinate to her; she is a terrible leader and would irritate those people. By leaving her outside the rank system Janeway cleverly reduces both problems: Seven only has the authority Janeway grants her, plus Seven's own personality, and anyone who has an issue with Seven can go to a senior officer to work it out.

Comment: If I remember correctly only 4 Maquis crew were given training in "Learning Curve" (I don't remember any talk of any more being given training?), but yeh you're right, the Maquis were the exception, not Seven or anyone else.

Comment: @Cai The four Marquis in Learning Curve were Academy wash-outs who were more of a drain on Voyager's resources than anything else. The training regiment they received was meant to whip them into a more productive state. This was based on their personality rather than their prior experience or training.

Comment: An addition to this is "why was Tom Paris wearing a starfleet uniform" He was a criminal who got released into janeway's custody, but wasn't a part of the crew. It makes as much sense as why were Voyager's Senior Staff 1 captain, 1 LtC, 2 Maquis, a criminal, and an Ensign.

Comment: @Durakken Tom Paris is a good point. He was an ex-Starfleet, ex-Maquis criminal along as an advisor. Janeway reinstated his Starfleet rank of Lt. Jg.

Comment: After they were lost in the Delta Quadrant. He was in Uniform before hand though.

Comment: *Even on the Enterprise D Acting Ensign Wesley Crusher didn't get to wear a uniform until he completed Starfleet Academy.* is not right. He got a field promotion to full ensign w/o completing the Acadamy, fled the captains ready room and returned to bridge in full uniform (*Ménage à Troi*).

Comment: @Ghanima You're right! I will correct.

Comment: @Durakken I just had another look at *Caretaker* and you're right. He's a "Starfleet observer". I guess that grants him a uniform, but no rank insignia. I've altered the answer.

Comment: @Durakken " It makes as much sense as why were Voyager's Senior Staff 1 captain, 1 LtC, 2 Maquis, a criminal, and an Ensign." You forgot the holographic computer program.

Comment: In Lt. Barclay's holodeck fantasies of Voyager the Maquis wear their original clothes, not StarFleet uniforms. Presumably Barclay assumed that the normal protocol was applying, as he didn't know that Janeway had decided to integrate the crews.

Answer (score 33):

Seven of Nine is a civilian, rather than a member of Starfleet. Like the other civilian [waifs](http://i3.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6451234.ece/BINARY/Jennifer-Lien-as-her-character-Kes-in-Star-Trek-Voyager-in-1995.jpg) and [strays](http://voy.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/publicity/character/neelix/neelix_white_pb.jpg) that the ship [picks up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_recurring_characters_in_Star_Trek:_Voyager#Azan.2C_Rebi_and_Mezoti) on their adventures, she gets to wear whatever the heck she likes. Apparently [skin-tight catsuits](http://trekcore.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/latinum_seven.jpg) are her *preferred* outfit.

Where the Maquis are concerned, the situation is slightly different since they were *transferring* over from one ship (where they already had a rank and role) to another.

[image]

You may wish to note that Tuvok is most decidedly "anti" the idea of non-Starfleet members wearing Starfleet uniforms.

> **NEELIX:** *It's not impossible. Maybe. Perhaps not. But we'll find them. We'll need several containers of water to bring for barter. Do
> these, er, replicators make clothing as well?*
>
> **TUVOK:** *Yes.*
>
> **NEELIX:** *Will it make me a uniform like yours?*
>
> **TUVOK:** *No, it most certainly will not.*
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: Caretaker](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/101.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: The funny thing about that Tuvok / Neelix interaction is that Neelix would technically outrank him in some respects because Neelix would be a "Captain" with regard to his ship. But more over Neelix, by the end of the series has more Starfleet training than many of the Maquis. I think it was more his dislike of Neelix and belief that he was a passenger rather than a member of the crew. Seven I think he'd have been open to have her wearing an uniform since he probably saw her as part of the crew.

Comment: @Durakken - During the "Omega Directive" crisis, Captain Janeway points out that Seven has the collective knowledge of dozens of Starfleet captains. That being said, her actions (in that episode and many others) clearly demonstrate a signal lack of judgment & willingness to follow orders that would be required in a Starfleet officer.

Comment: Seven does follow orders better later on. Omega Directive is Early Season 5 and still early into her journey as a character... Also... She would have been a way better first officer than Chakotay imo, who you could argue is single handedly responsible for Janeway not being able to forge a long term alliance with the Borg for the Federation and resulted in STO's war with them and he disobeys and shows an amazing lack of judgement repeatedly and worse, without cause, where as Seven you can always say has cause simply due to her knowledge level.

Comment: @Durakken - Seven would make a terrible officer. She totally lacks any sense of adventure and she's very very risk-averse.

Comment: I'm not sure the Neelix / Tuvok relationship is the best example to go on but yeh this makes sense.

Comment: and you'd have another +1 for [Latinum Seven](http://trekcore.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/latinum_seven.jpg) if I could

Comment: I don't buy it. Seven also came from another ship where she had a rank and role (Seven of Nine, Tertiary Adjunct of Unimatrix 01).

Comment: @Valorum Since star trek protagonists only last for more than two episodes thanks to a massive plot shield, being risk more averse than other officers doesn't strike me as a terrible trait. Unless you expect starfleet officers to understand and exploit being favoured by fate.

Comment: @Schwern - A designation is not a rank

Comment: One thing to consider may be that Seven never had any formal training as a crew member, having been indoctrinated into a hive mind as a small child.

Comment: Lot of the Maquis (if not all) went to Star Fleet Academy and graduated therefore earned the uniform but Seven never did as she was a child at the time when taken by the borg

Comment: @Durakken: Not everyone is a "Captain" just because they have been on their own on a runabout or comparable for a while.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yeah they are ^.^ That's sorta how international military ranks work. Also Neelix does have military experience from what I recall so he does have an actual rank beyond Captain of a ship.

Comment: @Durakken - Worth asking as a separate question

Comment: @Durakken: Sisko remained a Commander throughout DS9's season 3 despite commanding the Defiant. And whether the ranking structure of an alien organization might in any way be compatible in such a way that it would be reasonable to "transfer" one's former rank is probably a whole other question (just see how incompatible academic degrees such as "Bachelor" are around the world, even though there often are only two or three of them in all and even after efforts to harmonize the systems have been made).

Comment: @Durakken Actually, Captain is both a position and a rank. To eliminate confusion (as a vessel should only have one captain), naval tradition has an embarked Marine captain addressed as one rank higher, "Major" while aboard ship. Neelix is very much the captain of his little vessel, but that is a position - he is a civilian and holds no rank.

Answer (score 14):

**Out-of-Universe:** that suit was designed to be sexy. Jeri Ryan, the Seven actor, is a professional model. The suit that Paramount chose for her was a breast-enhancing corset suit to make her "borg perfection" obvious. As explained by [director Jesús Salvador Trevino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_of_Nine#Attire):

> Ryan wore a silver jumpsuit for the first few episodes, which director
>   Jesús Salvador Treviño said that during the filming of the episode
>   "Day of Honor" caused problems as "almost any camera angle inevitably
>   winds up emphasising her sexuality."

**In-Universe:** I think I recall Seven once saying she preferred that suit because it was made out of some sort of advanced fabric that offered superior thermal protection, fabric strength, etc. She liked it because it was more efficient, so to speak, than regular uniforms.

Comment: Could you add a citation or quote for either part? While people can search for it, it’ll be more convenient if it is all here.

Comment: What Adamant said. If this is so easy to find, instead of expecting everyone to go looking for information to back up your claims, provide a few links (and perhaps also relevant quotations from the linked pages) yourself.

Comment: "Problems" - not according to the network

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but I thought the in-universe reason was that the catsuit was a more fashionable version of the undersheath that Borg drones wear.

Answer (score 0):

Seven wasn't in starfleet that's a Technical explanation. The Maquis were exception given the size of their ranks, namely that several were former Starfleet officiers themselves so it made sense for Janeways sense of discipline and authority to have them in uniforms. 
Jeri Ryan was brought in just to attract more male viewers. 
To do that they gave her a Catwoman style uniform that accentuated her figure.
one whose design was simple but also was an homage to her former borg heritage. In particular a segmented armored appearance, No exposure of human flesh except her head and hands, the piping and seams resembling the tubes and nodules in her body.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Seven of Nine’s catsuits are medicinal in function.

The EMH Doctor constructed her catsuit to assist with the regeneration of her necrotizing skin, which was severely damaged by her Borg assimilation.

Comment: This sounds like it would be a great answer.... If you can offer a shred of evidence to back it up.

Comment: In The Gift, the EMH says of the suit, “Fashion, of course, is hardly my forte. Nevertheless, I’ve managed to balance functionality and aesthetics in a pleasing enough manner.” I’m sure there’s a later episode where he elaborates on the reason for why he designed the original suit, but I can’t find it.